# redirection on custom submit handler

Tags: drupal-7, form-submit, hook-form-alter

so basically this is my 2nd day in this problem.

i have my module `send_xml.module`

```
function send_xml_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'send_xml_submit_function';
}

function send_xml_submit_function($form, &$form_state){
    $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];
    $form_state['redirect'] = array(
        'mylink', array(
             'query' => array(
                  'email' => $email,
                  'password' => $password,
              ),
             ),
            );
```

but it does not redirect after the process in `mylink`, it just refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_form_alter` like this:

```
function send_xml_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'user_register_form':
            $form['#submit'] = array('send_xml_submit_function');
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
}

function send_xml_submit_function($form, &$form_state){
    // call default submit -- this is default submit action for register form
    user_register_submit($form, $form_state);
    // if you use profile2 to create fields in register form then call this function too
    profile2_form_submit_handler($form, $form_state);


    $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];
    $form_state['redirect'] = array(
      'mylink', array(
         'query' => array(
              'email' => $email,
              'password' => $password,
          ),
         ),
        );
}
```

I had same problem weeks ago and this is way I solved it, actually I have no clear idea why this work and why appending `#submit` don't work.
I checked drupal `user_register_submit` code and seems like it clear `$form_state['redirect']` to redirect user to `<front>`.

Comment: thanks for the reply

isnt that the same as above? form_alter is a for all the forms, then you'll just use a switch case in side to determine what form is it...

that's why i use hook_form_FORMID_alter to specify what form ill use, specifically.

i did that to. but it's the same.

maybe the `$form_state['redirect']` value is changed somewhere else? that's why my declaration here is overrides? but where and how can i know this?? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) function:

```
function send_xml_submit_function($form, &$form_state){
  $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
  $password = $form_state['values']['pass'];

  drupal_goto('REDIRECT_pATH', array('query' => array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it isnt good to put `drupal_goto` inside a your custom submit handler because there might still be processes not yet done and they will be broken...need to redirect after all the prcess are done that's why i used `$form_state['redirect']`

Comment: @KarlMichaelLinantud Not agree.. If you add you own submit callback to the end of `#submit` element(array) there won't be any processes not yet done (it is you control which process has been done and which is left)..